# Recuperar una base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Elimine una base de datos desde el explorador de objetos, saben si existe alguna manera de recuperarla con algun programa o algo por el estilo ?

Comment: Puedes verificar si tienes la base de datos en c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\

Comment: Ya verifique y no tengo la base de datos

Comment: Va estar mas dificil recuperarla

Comment: Lo se, pero lo que me se ocurre es descargar un programa que recupere archivos borrados

Comment: @ARR sin tener una copia de seguridad es imposible recuperarla ya que los archivos `MDF` y `LDF` se eliminan, por lo tanto no podrá. Si opta por usar un programa para recuperar archivos Debe hacerlo antes que se sobrescriba mas información en el disco duro y si tiene suerte podrá encontrar algo.

Comment: De echo lo primero que busque fueron los archivos `MDF` y `LDF` y lo que estoy haciendo a continuacion es ejecutar el programa Recuva, no se si pueda recuperar los archivos  `MDF` y `LDF` pero no pierdo nada intentandolo

Comment: Puedes intentar usar GetData Back , tambien es bueno recuperando documentos y/o archivos eliminados.

Comment: a un programa que le tengo mucho respeto "R-Studio", la licencia es cara y vale la inversión https://www.r-studio.com/Buy-Data-Recovery-Software.html